# Is it possible to use single xsl fo stylesheet for two xml documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Is it possible to use single xsl fo stylesheet for 2 xml documents with one containing one table and the other two tables. The two tables have the same header.so i think is it possible to use a for each loop and depending on the tables generate the pdf.Also i would like to put a gap between the two tables.

the table can be in html/xhtml also but i will parse it to xml

xml file 1

```
<Root>
<Table>
.......
.
.
.
.
.
</Table>
</Root>
```

xml file 2

```
<Root>
<Table>
.......
.
.
.
.
.
</Table>

<Table>
.......
.
.
.
.
.
</Table>
</Root>
```

also is it possible to column size depending on the content inside each cell.for example if the row3,cell 1 has the maximum data then put that as the column size.

```
-----------------------------------------------------

column1    column2   column3
-----------------------------------------------------

1           abc         1
------------------------------------------------------

2          xxxxxxx      1


12312122      0         1
```

here the column width of 1st column should be of row3 cell.
column width of 2st column should be of row2 cell.
column width of 3st column should be of header cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A xslt stylesheet can handle many xml files. Depending on what version of XSLT you are using you can use the doc() or document() function (xslt 1.0) or collection() if you are using xslt 2.0.

for example:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="doc-available('path/to/xml/file')">
            <xsl:for-each select="doc('path/to/xml/file')">
            <!--do work here-->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:comment>file not found</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```